# Delete only files using S3 DeleteObject keeping directory structure intact

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to delete only the files under a particular directory in Amazon S3,
My file path is as follows

```
s3://{s3_bucket}/folder1/sub-folder2/sub-folder3/sub-folder4/sub-folder5/sub-folder6/sub-folder7/sub-folder8/sub-folder9/file.txt
```

I used the following code  to delete the files alone from the above directory structure

```
public static void deleteFilesInDirectory(String bucketName, String prefix) {       
        String delimiter = "/";
        if (!prefix.endsWith(delimiter)) {
            prefix += delimiter;
        }
        ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(prefix);

        ObjectListing objects = s3client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);       
        for(S3ObjectSummary summary:objects.getObjectSummaries())
        {
            if(!summary.getKey().endsWith("/"))
            {
            s3client.deleteObject(bucketName, summary.getKey());
            }           
        }      
    }
```

The above code  deleted the directory sub-folder3/sub-folder4/sub-folder5/sub-folder6/sub-folder7/sub-folder8/sub-folder9/

But i need the above directory structure.

Is my understanding of api correct ,can someone help me with this

Is there any other alternate  to delete only the files under a particular s3 directory using java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

S3 has no directory structure.  It's a totally flat filesystem.  An object named `foo/bar` is just that: an object named `foo/bar`, not an object named `bar` in a directory named `foo`.  If you deleted `foo/bar`, and there were no other objects in the bucket starting with the string `foo/`, it would look like the "directory" `foo` was deleted, but it never existed in the first place.  So, to create an object named `foo/bar` again, you don't need to create a directory named `foo/` first; just create an object named `foo/bar`.

Answer (score 0):

A "key" in S3 is similar to a file path:

http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some/path/to/use
... is in a bucket named bucket and has a key of some/path/to/use.

It's not actually a path though, because there are no folders. The S3 key is just the file name for a file in one big directory (the entire bucket). S3 keys can contain /, but it has no special meaning.

In other words, having an object named some/object doesn't tell you anything about the object some (it might or might not exist -- the two objects are not related).

However, you can request keys with a specific prefix, so I could say "give me all keys starting with some/path/to/ and it will return some/path/to/use. It looks like "listing a directory", but it's really just asking for files that start with a specific string of characters.

EDIT:

I looked at the JavaDocs and this is the function signature I see (for AmazonS3Client):

```
public void deleteObject(java.lang.String bucketName,
                     java.lang.String key)
              throws AmazonClientException,
                     AmazonServiceException
```